# MySQL 5.6 on CentOS 6.5 Failed Start

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, mysql-5.6, centos6.5

I have a virtual machine of CentOS 6.5 installed on **Microsoft Azure** platform. I installed MySQL 5.6 (mysql-community-release-el6-5.noarch.rpm) through ***yum*** package manager to install successful. But when issue `sudo service mysql start` command, then failed start daemon.

Anyone can help?

I list out the mysql.log for reference.

Start MySQL service result
[image]

```
2016-05-22T11:20:23.466749Z mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql

2016-05-22T11:20:24.785650Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).

2016-05-22T11:20:24.786553Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.12) starting as process 56736 ...

2016-05-22T11:20:24.913913Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available

2016-05-22T11:20:24.914072Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins

2016-05-22T11:20:24.914080Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event muteness

2016-05-22T11:20:24.914088Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __sync_synchronize() is used for memory barrier

2016-05-22T11:20:24.914092Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use lib 1.2.3

2016-05-22T11:20:24.914098Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO

2016-05-22T11:20:24.914346Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1

2016-05-22T11:20:24.914461Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions

2016-05-22T11:20:24.974644Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M

2016-05-22T11:20:25.063114Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool

2016-05-22T11:20:25.072781Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().

2016-05-22T11:20:25.083557Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The Auto-extending innodb_system data file './ibdata1' is of a different size 640 pages (rounded down to MB) than specified in the .cnf file: initial 768 pages, max 0 (relevant if non-zero) pages!

2016-05-22T11:20:25.083578Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error

2016-05-22T11:20:25.793568Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.

2016-05-22T11:20:25.793610Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.

2016-05-22T11:20:25.793616Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.

2016-05-22T11:20:25.793620Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2016-05-22T11:20:25.794138Z 0 [Note] Binlog end

2016-05-22T11:20:25.794197Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'

2016-05-22T11:20:25.794207Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'

2016-05-22T11:20:25.795580Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2016-05-22T11:20:25.837272Z mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36804/mysql-5-6-failure

Comment: I follow this stepsUninstall MySQL, mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql_old and Reinstall MySQL, then resolve the error.